# Evaluating logical expressions recognized by ANTLR using the System.Linq.Expressions namespace

Tags: c#, linq, antlr, antlr4, boolean-expression

I've defined a grammar, which I have to parse in C# and evaluate the resulted "constraints" on a list of dictionaries. The grammar is mainly boolean algebra.

Here you can check it:

```
grammar Constraint;

expr
    :   implyExpr
    ;

implyExpr
    :   orExpr
    |   leftOp=orExpr IMPLY rightOp=orExpr
    ;
    
orExpr
    :   andExpr
    |   leftOp=andExpr OR rightOp=andExpr
    ;
    
andExpr
    :   primaryExpr
    |   leftOp=primaryExpr AND rightOp=primaryExpr
    ;
    
primaryExpr
    :   trueExpr
    |   falseExpr
    |   parenExpr
    |   notParenExpr
    |   statement
    ;
    
trueExpr
    :   TRUE
    ;
    
falseExpr
    :   FALSE
    ;
    
parenExpr
    :   LPAREN expr RPAREN
    ;
    
notParenExpr
    :   NOT LPAREN expr RPAREN
    ;
    
statement
    :   eqValStatement
    |   notEqValStatement
    |   inListStatement
    |   notInListStatement
    ;
    
eqValStatement
    :   key=STR EQ value=val
    ;
    
notEqValStatement
    :   key=STR NEQ value=val
    ;
    
inListStatement
    :   key=STR EQ list=lst
    ;
    
notInListStatement
    :   key=STR NEQ list=lst
    ;

lst
    :   LBRACK values+=val (COMMA values+=val)* RBRACK
    ;

val
    :   strVal
    |   nullVal
    ;

strVal
    :   value=STR
    ;
    
nullVal
    :   NULL
    ;

// Lexer

IMPLY:  '->';
OR:     '|';
AND:    '&';
TRUE:   'true';
FALSE:  'false';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
NOT:    '!';
EQ:     '=';
NEQ:    '!=';
LBRACK: '[';
RBRACK: ']';
COMMA:  ',';
NULL:   'null';
STR: [a-zA-Z0-9-_]+;
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

My question is that could I use this namespace for my goal or shall I use different delegates, which would take 2 delegates as parameters and would return with a bool value according to the implemented behaviour?

I'm still at the design phase, what I've done already is the grammar definition and generating the listenerbase class for it.

Comment: You need to create a delegate.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/delegates#204-delegate-compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using delegates in the end.
I generated a Predicate for each expression and combined them together.
I've also integrated the recognition of the grammar into the listener class, in this way providing a simple interface for getting a predicate from an expression.

Here's the most of it:

```cs
public class ConstraintEvaluator : ConstraintBaseListener
{
    
    public Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>>? Evaluate(string input)
    {
        _exprStack.Clear();
        _strStack.Clear();
        
        var stream = CharStreams.fromString(input);
        ITokenSource lexer = new ConstraintLexer(stream);
        ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ConstraintParser parser = new(tokens);
        IParseTree tree = parser.expr();
        ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(this, tree);
        return Result;
    }

    private Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>>? Result { get; set; }
    
    private readonly Stack<Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>>> _exprStack = new();
    private readonly Stack<string?> _strStack = new();
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> ImplicationFactory(Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> left, Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> right)
    {
        return config => !left(config) || right(config);
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> OrFactory(Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> left, Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> right)
    {
        return config => left(config) || right(config);
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> AndFactory(Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> left, Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> right)
    {
        return config => left(config) && right(config);
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> NotFactory(Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> expr)
    {
        return config => !expr(config);
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> EqValFactory(string key, string? value)
    {
        return config =>
        {
            if (config.All(x => x.Key != key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(KeyNotFoundError(key));
            }
            return config.Find(x => x.Key == key)?.Value == value;
        };
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> NotEqValFactory(string key, string? value)
    {
        return config =>
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return config.All(x => x.Key != key);
            }
            if (config.All(x => x.Key != key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(KeyNotFoundError(key));
            }
            return config.Find(x => x.Key == key)?.Value != value;
        };
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> InListFactory(string key, List<string?> values)
    {
        return config =>
        {
            if (config.All(x => x.Key != key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(KeyNotFoundError(key));
            }
            // if x.Value is null, it means that it is a flag and the values list should contain the null value too,
            // to allow the flag to be set (usually the flag shouldn't be allowed to have any other value, than null)
            return values.Contains(config.Find(x => x.Key == key)?.Value);
        };
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> NotInListFactory(string key, List<string?> values)
    {
        return config =>
        {
            if (config.All(x => x.Key != key))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(KeyNotFoundError(key));
            }
            return !values.Contains(config.Find(x => x.Key == key)?.Value);
        };
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> FalseFactory()
    {
        return _ => false;
    }
    
    private static Predicate<List<ConfigurationItemHeader>> TrueFactory()
    {
        return _ => true;
    }
    
    private static string StackNotEmptyError(string stackName, string methodName)
    {
        return $"{stackName} is not empty after {methodName}!";
    }
    
    private static string KeyNotFoundError(string key)
    {
        return $"Key <{key}> not found in config!";
    }
    
    public override void ExitExpr(ConstraintParser.ExprContext context)
    {
        Result = _exprStack.Peek();
    }
    
    public override void ExitImplyExpr(ConstraintParser.ImplyExprContext context)
    {
        if (context.leftOp == null || context.rightOp == null) return;
        var right = _exprStack.Pop();
        var left = _exprStack.Pop();
        if (_exprStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_exprStack), nameof(ExitImplyExpr)));
        }

        _exprStack.Push(ImplicationFactory(left, right));
    }
    
    public override void ExitOrExpr(ConstraintParser.OrExprContext context)
    {
        if (context.leftOp == null || context.rightOp == null) return;
        var right = _exprStack.Pop();
        var left = _exprStack.Pop();
        if (_exprStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_exprStack), nameof(ExitOrExpr)));
        }
        _exprStack.Push(OrFactory(left, right));
    }
    
    public override void ExitAndExpr(ConstraintParser.AndExprContext context)
    {
        if (context.leftOp == null || context.rightOp == null) return;
        var right = _exprStack.Pop();
        var left = _exprStack.Pop();
        if (_exprStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_exprStack), nameof(ExitAndExpr)));
        }
        _exprStack.Push(AndFactory(left, right));
    }
    
    public override void ExitTrueExpr(ConstraintParser.TrueExprContext context)
    {
        _exprStack.Push(TrueFactory());
    }
    
    public override void ExitFalseExpr(ConstraintParser.FalseExprContext context)
    {
        _exprStack.Push(FalseFactory());
    }
    
    public override void ExitNotParenExpr(ConstraintParser.NotParenExprContext context)
    {
        var expr = _exprStack.Pop();
        if (_exprStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_exprStack), nameof(ExitNotParenExpr)));
        }
        _exprStack.Push(NotFactory(expr));
    }
    
    public override void ExitEqValStatement(ConstraintParser.EqValStatementContext context)
    {
        var key = context.key.Text;
        var value = _strStack.Pop();
        if (_strStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_strStack), nameof(ExitEqValStatement)));
        }
        _exprStack.Push(EqValFactory(key, value));
    }
    
    public override void ExitNotEqValStatement(ConstraintParser.NotEqValStatementContext context)
    {
        var key = context.key.Text;
        var value = _strStack.Pop();
        if (_strStack.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(StackNotEmptyError(nameof(_strStack),nameof(ExitNotEqValStatement)));
        }
        _exprStack.Push(NotEqValFactory(key, value));
    }
    
    public override void ExitInListStatement(ConstraintParser.InListStatementContext context)
    {
        var key = context.key.Text;
        var values = _strStack.ToList();
        _strStack.Clear();
        _exprStack.Push(InListFactory(key, values));
    }
    
    public override void ExitNotInListStatement(ConstraintParser.NotInListStatementContext context)
    {
        var key = context.key.Text;
        var values = _strStack.ToList();
        _strStack.Clear();
        _exprStack.Push(NotInListFactory(key, values));
    }
    
    public override void ExitStrVal(ConstraintParser.StrValContext context)
    {
        _strStack.Push(context.value.Text);
    }
    
    public override void ExitNullVal(ConstraintParser.NullValContext context)
    {
        _strStack.Push(null);
    }
}
```

In the end I used List of ConfigurationItems, which have Key and Value properties, bc. of the domain requirements of my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simple extend the visitor generated by ANTLR (you'd need to add the `-visitor` parameter when generating the parser classes). That could look like this:

```cs
public class ConstraintEvalVisitor : ConstraintBaseVisitor<object?>
{
  // eval
  //  : expr EOF
  //  ;
  public override object? VisitEval(ConstraintParser.EvalContext context)
    => this.Visit(context.expr());

  public override object? VisitExpr(ConstraintParser.ExprContext context)
    => this.Visit(context.implyExpr());

  public override object? VisitImplyExpr(ConstraintParser.ImplyExprContext context)
  {
    if (context.IMPLY() == null)
    {
      return this.Visit(context.orExpr().Single());
    }

    var lhs = this.Visit(context.leftOp) as bool?;
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.rightOp) as bool?;

    return lhs!.Value ? rhs! : true;
  }

  public override object? VisitOrExpr(ConstraintParser.OrExprContext context)
  {
    if (context.OR() == null)
    {
      return this.Visit(context.andExpr().Single());
    }

    var lhs = this.Visit(context.leftOp) as bool?;
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.rightOp) as bool?;

    return lhs!.Value || rhs!.Value;
  }

  public override object? VisitAndExpr(ConstraintParser.AndExprContext context)
  {
    if (context.AND() == null)
    {
      return this.Visit(context.primaryExpr().Single());
    }

    var lhs = this.Visit(context.leftOp) as bool?;
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.rightOp) as bool?;

    return lhs!.Value && rhs!.Value;
  }

  public override object? VisitPrimaryExpr(ConstraintParser.PrimaryExprContext context)
  {
    if (context.trueExpr() != null)
      return true;

    if (context.falseExpr() != null)
      return false;

    if (context.parenExpr() != null)
      return this.Visit(context.parenExpr().expr());

    if (context.notParenExpr() != null)
      return this.Visit(context.notParenExpr());

    return this.Visit(context.statement());
  }

  public override object? VisitNotParenExpr(ConstraintParser.NotParenExprContext context)
    => this.Visit(context.expr()) as bool?;

  public override object? VisitStatement(ConstraintParser.StatementContext context)
  {
    if (context.eqValStatement() != null)
      return this.Visit(context.eqValStatement());

    if (context.notEqValStatement() != null)
      return this.Visit(context.notEqValStatement());

    if (context.inListStatement() != null)
      return this.Visit(context.inListStatement());

    return this.Visit(context.notInListStatement());
  }

  public override object? VisitEqValStatement(ConstraintParser.EqValStatementContext context)
  {
    var lhs = context.STR().GetText();
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.val()) as string;

    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
  }

  public override object? VisitNotEqValStatement(ConstraintParser.NotEqValStatementContext context)
  {
    var lhs = context.STR().GetText();
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.val()) as string;

    return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
  }

  public override object? VisitInListStatement(ConstraintParser.InListStatementContext context)
  {
    var lhs = context.STR().GetText();
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.lst()) as List<object?>;

    return rhs!.Contains(lhs);
  }

  public override object? VisitNotInListStatement(ConstraintParser.NotInListStatementContext context)
  {
    var lhs = context.STR().GetText();
    var rhs = this.Visit(context.lst()) as List<object?>;

    return !rhs!.Contains(lhs);
  }

  public override object? VisitVal(ConstraintParser.ValContext context)
    => context.strVal() == null ? null : context.strVal().STR().GetText();

  public override object? VisitLst(ConstraintParser.LstContext context)
    => context._values.Select(this.Visit).ToList();
}
```

It can be tested like this:

```cs
Evaluate("true -> true");
Evaluate("true -> false");
Evaluate("false -> true");
Evaluate("false -> false");
Evaluate("false | false");
Evaluate("false | true");
Evaluate("true & false");
Evaluate("true & true");
Evaluate("(true) & true");
Evaluate("A = A");
Evaluate("A = B");
Evaluate("A != A");
Evaluate("A != B");
Evaluate("B = [A, B]");
Evaluate("A = [B, C, D]");

static void Evaluate(string expression)
{
  var lexer = new ConstraintLexer(CharStreams.fromString(expression));
  var parser = new ConstraintParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
  var answer = new ConstraintEvalVisitor().Visit(parser.eval());

  Console.WriteLine($"{expression,-20}{answer}");
}
```

which will print:

```
true -> true        True
true -> false       False
false -> true       True
false -> false      True
false | false       False
false | true        True
true & false        False
true & true         True
(true) & true       True
A = A               True
A = B               False
A != A              False
A != B              True
B = [A, B]          True
A = [B, C, D]       False
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I've completed already (yesterday) the challenge by using delegates and factory methods, which combined together the different expressions. Your solution is also correct, I'll share mine for the future too.